# How to compare values in two arrays to find one or more matches in? [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to compare a input value with two paragrapah to check if the input value exists in both paragraph. So, I did this below. But the code is not working well :/. Could someone explain how to do it?

```
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_district" id="billing_district" placeholder="" value="">
    <p class="regions">Dias Macedo, Itaperi, Passaré, Taquara, Serrinha</p>
    <p class="regions">Dias Macedo, Dendê, Edson Queiroz, Taquara</p>
    <p class="regions">Jereissati, Dendê, Forquilha, Centro, Taquara</p>


jQuery(function ($) {
    var a = $('#billing_district').val().normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '').toLowerCase().split();
    var b = $('.regions').text().normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '').toLowerCase().split(", ");

    var index = $.grep(b, function (element, index) {
        if ($.inArray(element, a) != -1) {
            console.log(element);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So where's the problem? Define what's "not working well."

Comment: You mean at least in both paragraphs or it should be strict in both and when it appears in the third paragraph it should false?

Comment: Hello! @Marc and svyatis.lviv I'm trying to check if the value from input exists in all 3 paragraphs. But, the way I did, if exist in two or only one the results is "true".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, though you did not specify that the code should look at whole terms between commas. This code outputs true even if two letters occur in all the p's.
But you could add an extra loop to check the splitted strings.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  const $input = $('#billing_district');
  const b = $('.regions');
  $('#billing_district').on('keyup', function(){
    let a = $input.val();
    let count = 0
    $.each(b, function(i, p) {
      console.log($(p).text().replace(/\s/g, ""),a);
      if ($(p).text().replace(/\s/g, "").includes(a)) {
        count++;
      }
    });
    let valueIsInAllParagraphs = (count == 3);
    console.log(valueIsInAllParagraphs);    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_district" id="billing_district" placeholder="" value="">
<p class="regions">Dias Macedo, Itaperi, Passaré, Taquara, Serrinha</p>
<p class="regions">Dias Macedo, Dendê, Edson Queiroz, Taquara</p>
<p class="regions">Jereissati, Dendê, Forquilha, Centro, Taquara</p>
```

Comment: Hello @Esger, I'm trying to check the whole word get from input and check if exists in all 3 p's. With your idea I'm trying in new way. Many thanks! If works, I'll update here.